# What is pool in SOLARIS? Also how it is related to ZONES?

Tags: solaris, pool, solaris-10, zfs

I have read and got a clear idea on ZONE concept in SOLARIS. I am a newbie, so little confused with pools in SOLARIS. How does this come in between ZONES and also give me an example so that I can be able to understand clearly. It will be helpful if I get a clear architecture diagram of ZONES and POOLS in the same figure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pools, more precisely resource pools, is a Solaris feature allowing to define a set of resources grouped together. You can bind projects to pools and then dedicated resources to be used by the processes in that project.

Resource pool predates the availability of zones with Solaris.

When you create a zone with the dedicated_cpu property set, a resource pool is automatically created and associated with the zone.

Answer (score 0):

Pools are just blobs of aggregated storage, built out of different vdevs (virtual devices, usually backed by multiple disks). Inside those pools, you can create two things:

- file systems: ZFS file systems, similar to traditional directories/shares
- zvols: ZFS volumes, similar to traditional block storage

Both can be shared by various protocols, although usually file systems are shared with SMB/AFS/NFS for file access, while zvols are shared as virtual hard drives via iSCSI (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6r60/index.html for details).

Instead of sharing them over the network, you can also mount them on the same system and use them as internal virtual hard drives - usually this is done to give each zone a different disk where it has full access.

So, in short, zvols or file systems inside ZFS storage *pools* provide storage for Solaris or illumos *zones*.

Comment: I strongly suspect the OP to be asking about (resource) pools, not zpools.

Comment: @jlliagre The question was tagged with 'zfs', so I assumed zpools. But two different answers are more helpful than just one either way. :)